# A question about the consequence of Prime Avoidance.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I have found the following statement:

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $x$ is a non-zero divisor of $R$. Let $P$ be a prime ideal associated to $xR$. Then by Prime Avoidance there exists a non-zero divisor $y\in R$ such that  $P=xR:_R y \,\,\,\,( xR:_R y:=\{a\in R;ay\in xR\}).$

Can someone please explain how we get such $y$ from Prime Avoidance.

Comment: [Here](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/HM/PMH2/) are some Commutative Algebra notes by Ruibin Zhang. Reading "Primary Decomposition-1" will answer your question, which is one direction of the first uniqueness theorem of primary decomposition. It is stated on page 7 of the pdf (page 66 of the notes overall). As you can see in the proof, Prime avoidance is actually used for the direction you are not asking about. You will also need to reach "Primary Decomposition-2" to see that ideals in Noetherian rings are decomposable. If you have any problems reading the notes, feel free to ask here again.